# WCF + AD FS Active Federation + Windows Authentication

Tags: adfs

I am facing issue in creating claim aware WCF service using windows authentication.

Enabled windows authentication in IIS. Disabled annonymous authentication.

Service :

Binding :

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ws2007FederationHttpBindingBindingdetails">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Default" >

          <issuerMetadata address="STSAddress/mex" />
          <claimTypeRequirements>
            <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" isOptional="false" />
            <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname" isOptional="false" />
          </claimTypeRequirements>
        </message>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

Facing below issue if trying to open the service

The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'WS2007FederationHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the  element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.

Is there any issue in binding? WS2007FederationHttpBinding doesnt have either of security modes Transport or TransportCredentialOnly